# Bayesian linear regression using pymc

Tags: bayesian, pymc3

Assume three features: $x_1,x_2,x_3,$ and a continuous label $y.$ I want to use `pymc` in python to fit a `Bayesian linear regression` based on training samples. I was asked for two questions:

1. At what $x_3$, $y$ is a maximum?
2. Provide a distribution of this $x_3$ (that maximizes $y$).

For 1, I understand as we should first fix the left features say $x_1 = 1, x_2 = 2.$ Then numerically find $x_3$ to maximize the mean of posterior distribution: $m(x_3) = E[y|x_1=1,x_2=2,x_3].$

I am not familiar with pymc,

1. how do we call the above posterior distribution $P(y|x_1=1,x_2=2,x_3)$?
2. is `pm.plot_posterior` the expected distribution for question 2?

I doubt that here `maximum` is the maximum of probability i.e. MAP estimation or it seems not easy to solve.

Comment: [What is your model?](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0BTNVFR65)

Comment: What do you mean with your first question? Are you looking for the specific _value_ of $x_{3}$ that is associated with the maximum value of $y$? If so, that is much less a regression problem than a sorting problem.